# Speech server - WCF service to return wav as a byte array

Tags: c#, wcf

I made a WCF in order to works as a Speech Server.

My contract:

```
namespace RybenaTTSWS
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IRybenaTTS
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate="{text}",BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
        byte[] Speak(string text);
    }
}
```

My implementation:

```
namespace RybenaTTSWS
{
    public class RybenaTTS : IRybenaTTS
    {
        public byte[] Speak(string text)
        {
            OutgoingWebResponseContext context = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;

            SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            synth.Rate = 1;
            synth.Volume = 100;
            synth.SelectVoice("Microsoft Maria Desktop");
            synth.SetOutputToWaveStream(ms);

            synth.Speak(text);

            synth.SetOutputToNull();

            context.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpResponseHeader.CacheControl, "public");
            context.ContentType = "audio/wav";
            context.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;

            return ms.GetBuffer();
        }
    }
}
```

I can consume this WCF, but I want call it directly as src of an audio tag on my client's HTML. The problem is that returns something that I think it's not a binary array.

For example, when I call it via browser as

```
http://172.16.0.107/RybenaTTSWS/RybenaTTS.svc/Speak?text=sometext
```

on Microsoft Edge, it returns

```
<base64Binary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">UklGRoTWAABXQVZFZ.....=</base64Binary>
```

On Chrome, it returns "nothing", to say so; just a blank page (on Developer Tools is says me `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type audio/wav`).

What am I missing?

Comment: Try to return Stream instead of byte array, as in this [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc681221.aspx)

Comment: @ArtavazdBalayan No differences. Same behaviour and messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've got it to work...

Return a Stream, but do not forget to set Stream's Position to 0 before returning it!

I really would like to know why, but anyway... worked!

```
    public Stream Speak(string text)
    {
        OutgoingWebResponseContext context = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;

        SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        synth.Rate = 1;
        synth.Volume = 100;
        synth.SelectVoice("Microsoft Maria Desktop");
        synth.SetOutputToWaveStream(ms);

        synth.Speak(text);

        synth.SetOutputToNull();

        context.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpResponseHeader.CacheControl, "public");
        context.ContentType = "audio/wav";
        context.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;


        ms.Position = 0;    // <<<------------ That's the secret!!!

        return ms;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is work example in Google Chrome and Firefox. In IE I'm getting exception "System.ArgumentException: Specified value has invalid Control characters. Parameter name: value. ". It seems to me that IE uses some strange param in HTTP request.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<audio src="http://localhost:8000/WaveService/GetWave" autoplay>
  Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
</body>
</html>
```

C# code:

```
namespace WaveSampe
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.ServiceModel;
    using System.ServiceModel.Description;
    using System.ServiceModel.Web;

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IWaveService
    {
        [WebGet]
        Stream GetWave();
    }
    public class WaveService : IWaveService
    {
        public Stream GetWave()
        {
            var resp = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;
            resp.ContentType = "audio/wav";
            // Clear caches
            resp.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpResponseHeader.CacheControl, "no-cache");
            resp.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpResponseHeader.Pragma, "no-cache");
            resp.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpResponseHeader.Expires, "0");

            // Wave example. Source is http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/documents/audioformats/wave/Samples/AFsp/M1F1-Alaw-AFsp.wav
            return new FileStream("example.wav", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string baseAddress = "http://localhost:8000/WaveService";
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WaveService), new Uri(baseAddress));
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IWaveService), new WebHttpBinding(), "").Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Service is running");
            Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
            Console.ReadLine();
            host.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No success! Returning a stream, no data arrives on the client; returning a byte array, the array arrives on the client as base64binary... :(

Comment: @Nilo Paim, Hmm, very stange. Here is the screen of my [Google Chrome](http://oi63.tinypic.com/kciesw.jpg)